# cakePHP save as pdf using PHPExcel

Tags: cakephp, pdf, pdf-generation, phpexcel, mpdf

I've been trying to save my excel file as pdf using:

PHPExcel - https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel

My framework is cakePHP 2.3 and I can successfully create excel files but saving to pdf just won't work. Read the documentation, tried the examples, searched all over the internet but no dice.

As far as I know, the link above consists of phpExcel 1.8 and mPDF 5.4. I'm using its PHPExcel Helper.

I can't even get the example from phpexcel working.

```
    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
    $rendererLibrary = 'mPDF5.4';
    $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../libraries/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary;

    if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
            $rendererName,
            $rendererLibraryPath
        )) {
        die(
            'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
            '<br />' .
            'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
        );
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.pdf"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

If I can only produce even a hello world pdf using PHPExcel on https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel , that would be great.

BTW, I can already produce .xlsx documents with the helper, I only need to render it directly to pdf.

Any ideas?

Comment: What PDF rendering engine are you using? Is PHPExcel configured to use it?

Comment: Show your code! and explain what exactly doesn't work. Also please mention the versions of CakePHP, PHPExcel Plugin, PHPExcel and mPDF.

Comment: Updated the question, I'm sorry if I missed out on such important details (Just joined stackoverflow, don't know the ins and outs)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with like this

write function like below in pdf

```
       function pdfgenerate(){
            $objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('C:\Downloads\Report-1.xlsx');
            $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/Vendor/mpdf';
            $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;

            if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
                $rendererName,
                $rendererLibraryPath
            )) {
            die(
             'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
             '<br />' .
             'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
             );
            }
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$reportname.'.pdf"'); //tell browser what's the file name
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

            //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Orari');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF'); 
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
       }
```